# how to concatenate string and variable in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How to concatenate string with two adding variable use Vuejs.  i have used below code but string i am not able to concatenate to variables. please check and solve my issue.

```
<div id = "vue_det">
    <h1>Firstname : {{firstname}}</h1>
    <h1>Lastname : {{lastname}}</h1>
    <h1>{{test()}}</h1>
    </div>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/vue_instance.js"></script>
    <script>

     var  vm = new Vue({
   el: '#vue_det',
   data: {
      firstname : 10,
      lastname  : 20,

   },
   methods: {
      test : function() {

         return "result"+ this.firstname+this.lastname;
      }
   }
})
     </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: When you run the code you posted what happens? In what way does it not work? Do you see an error or is the output simply not what you wanted? If so, in what way is it wrong?

Comment: I believe you're looking for `return "result" + (this.firstname + this.lastname);`, with parentheses to ensure the numbers are added as numbers. I suggest giving them better names than `firstname` and `lastname` as those property names do imply that you'd want string concatenation and not number addition.

Answer (score 3):

you don't want a method, you want a computed.

```
computed: {
      test : function() {

         return "result = "+ (this.firstname+this.lastname);
      }
   }
```

then use it as if it wasn't a method, but another property

```
{{test}}
```

see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html for comprehensive documentation on computed properties.

Comment: i need anwser result =30

Comment: @sundar  for that, you need to bracket the int addition because it will turn into string concatination the way you have done it so  ```"result = " + (this.firstname+this.lastname)```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your string and variable in ():
something like this example for key

```
<li v-for="(x,i) in DataTable" :key="('item-' + x.Id)"></li>
```

Comment: Are you sure `(` `)` are required? I just tested it for vue2 and vue3, and neither of them requires braces.

Comment: Not necessary
But it avoids different issues that I faced myself.
Its presence is unnecessary in some cases.
In other cases, it avoids unexpected issues Because variable may contain unexpected characters. 
Its placement is suitable for all situations and avoids issues.

Comment: But then, in this case, the answer is misleading because, for this question, the missing braces are not the problem (and adding them is not the solution). You for sure can add the information that it makes sense to add them with an example why.

Comment: actually, my Answer is the best for him, he used function to concatenate string and variable my example more benefit to explain how he can concatenate. 

and this for his example 
<h1>{{('result'+ firstname  + lastname)}}</h1>

Comment: I didn't say that `{{ 'result'+ firstname + lastname }}` is wrong, I think that is actually a good solution. What I said is that your answer is `you need to add your string and variable in ()` but the `(` `)` are - for most cases (in case you are right) - is not required. That's why I said that the answer is misleading.

Comment: don't use ( ) if you want, but i recommended to use it, to avoids unexpected issues.